# jquery pass parameter to custom validation function

Tags: jquery

I wrote a custom method to validate whether price is valid. Eg. no alphabet etc. Hence I wrote a custom method. But I have no idea how to pass in value.

Method:

```
function checkIsPriceValid(input)
{

   alert(input);
    return false;
}
```

The form validation

```
$(function () { 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkIsPriceValid", function (value, element) {
  return checkIsPriceValid();
  //check whether checkbox dist and algo is checked
}, "Invalid number");  


$("#addProductForm").validate({
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    //error.appendTo(element.prev());
    error.insertAfter(element);
  },
  rules: { 


productName: { 
  required: true

},
productCategory:{ 
  required: true

},
productDescription: {
    required: true
},
productOrginalPrice:{
    required: true,
    checkIsPriceValid: this.val()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit - Sorry I was wrong about the first Param (Still not totally sure what it's for exactly).
I have never used the plugin but see if this works:

```
$(function () { 
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkIsPriceValid", function (value, element) {
  return checkIsPriceValid(value, element);
  //check whether checkbox dist and algo is checked
}, "Invalid number");
```

THen you should have

```
function checkIsPriceValid(value, element)
{

    alert(value);
    return false;
}
```

And for your validate method:

```
$("#addProductForm").validate({
 ...
productOrginalPrice:{
    required: true,
    checkIsPriceValid: "Price is invalid"
}
```

While I haven't used this plugin, just looking at the docs and other examples this plugin has a pretty ugly API. JQuery Tools validator is much better IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The name you use in the `addMethod` is totally arbitrary and does not have to match anything in the form.

First need to pass at least one argument to your `checkIsPriceValid` call inside the method. I am using `value` since that is what you re wanting to test.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkIsPriceValid", function (value, element) {
  return checkIsPriceValid(value);
  //check whether checkbox dist and algo is checked
}, "Invalid number");

function checkIsPriceValid(value){
    return value /* some test*/ ? true :false;

}
```

Then in the `validate.rules` object you use the method by adding the  method name as you have done, but assign value of `true` the same way as with other rules you've used like 'required'

```
productOrginalPrice:{
    required: true,
    checkIsPriceValid: true
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mpFz3/